# Where can i find the pricing details for API calls made using googleapiclient or cloud client library for python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I searched a lot throughout but, in some documentation, google has mentioned only pricing for cloud endpoints and Api gateways nowhere mention of Api calls to google cloud itself i was curious to know about the limitations of making API calls and if there is any where i can find the pricing list.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud does not charge for calling APIs. The service you are calling might charge based upon what the API does e.g. reading a secret or storing data but there is no change for the API call itself.